# Android marketplace; High Resolution Application Icon

Tags: android, google-play

This could be a dumb question, but I have submitted a few apps where I provided high resolution icons with specified values like:

```
512x512, 32-bit PNG; Max size of 1024KB.
```

both ways, by making a white background and transparent background.

My problem is:
1. why is it showing as a smaller icon in the Android market app, and
2. (this is lower priority; just out of curiosity) generally how long does it take to reflect your changes in the marketplace? I think it should be real time but it doesn't seem to be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The high resolution app is used on the http://market.android.com website as the banner icon (to the left of the feature graphic).
2. It depends on the changes. New app versions appear very quickly on the market (matter of minutes). Changes in graphics can take up to several hours. the Android Market App cache can also influence what you see, so to be sure I would suggest to clear the Android Market App cache from time to time.